# gcloud app deploy "This deployment has too many files"

Tags: node.js, deployment, github-actions, gcloud

I got this error even if I only have around 10 files in my directory.

I am using GithubActions to deploy my react app.

This is my current directory

```
├── app.yaml
└── build
    ├── index.html
    ├── favicon.ico
    └── ...etc (around 10files)
```

here, I execute 'gcloud app deploy' but it returns error and says " too many files"
Though I don't have 10000 files in current directory , I have more 10000files in hierarchy shallow directory, does app.yaml see there ??
I mean ,

```
.
├── node_modules ← 10000files
└── current_directory
    ├── app.yaml
    └── build
        ├── index.html
        ├── favicon.ico
        └── ...etc (around 10files)
```

this is error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000 files for this app.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest
  fieldViolations:
  - description: This deployment has too many files. New versions are limited to 10000
      files for this app.
    field: version.deployment.files[...]
```

this is my app.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs12
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: build
```

I'm not sure why they are trying to upload 10000files.
Thanks

Comment: I tried to add 'skip_files:
  - ^(.*/)?.*/node_modules/.*$' to app.yaml but nothing changed

Comment: Your hunch that the 10,000 files are in `node_modules` may be a red-herring. You say that you're using GitHub Actions, could it be that there's a (hidden) `.git` directory in `current_directory`? `ls -la ./current_directory`. You can add a [`.gcloudignore`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore) file to exclude e.g. `.git` (and possibly `node_modules`).